# passing an empty string as Directory parameter

Tags: c#, exception, directory, argumentnullexception

I was wandering if you can help with this. I have a console app which takes a string Directory as input.

I want to put in a check in place which allows  me to check if a user puts in an empty string I want the system to log an error such as ArgumentNullException.

```
string inputDirectory = "";
private void DoSomething(string inputDirectory)
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(inputDirectory)
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException e)
                {
                    Log.Error("program failed because the directory supplied was empty", e.Message);
                }
            }
```

The code is somewhere along these lines. Now the problem I have is the exception does not get thrown. Instead the program assumes that the directory is in the bin\Debug folder of the project. I am not sure what I need to do to stop execution of the program if the directory provided is "". I have done the if(inputDirectory == null) but this has not worked.
Any advice?
Thanks,
Jetnor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can add a check like;

```
string inputDirectory = "";
private void DoSomething(string inputDirectory)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDirectory)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(inputDirectory)
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        Log.Error("program failed because the directory supplied was empty", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I marked this as my answer because that is the actual structure that i used to throw and catch the exception in the end. All had the answer though with the String.isNullOrEmpty part. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure what I need to do to stop execution of the program if
>   the directory provided is "". I have done the if(inputDirectory ==
>   null) but this has not worked.

Use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or if you are using .Net 4.0 or higher, you can use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputDirectory))
 {
    //invalid input
 }
```

Both, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` and `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` would check against empty and null strings. `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` also checks for string containing all white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.IsNullOrWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
to check if the string is, well, null or whitespace only.

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(inputDirectory))
{
    throw new YourException("WhatEver");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` for checking the `Empty` Strings.

method `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` checks wether given string is either `null` or `Empty`.

if it founds given `String` is either `null` or `Empty` then it returns `true`.

**Step 1:** Check `inputDirectory` is Null or Empty by using String.IsNullOrEmpty() method.
**Step 2:** if the method returns `true` throw the `ArgumentNullException` using `throw` keyword.

Try This:

```
            string inputDirectory = "";
            private void DoSomething(string inputDirectory)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDirectory))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException();
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(inputDirectory)
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException e)
                {
                    Log.Error("program failed because the directory supplied was empty", e.Message);
                }
            }
```